# Select the previous header from the current header using jQuery

Tags: jquery, header, selector

Below is my HTML

```
 <H3 class='head'>About US</H3>
 <ul class='helper'>
  <li>
   <ul class='xtramenu'>
    <li>
     <H4 class='subhead'></H4>
    </li>
    <li>
     <H4 class='subhead'></H4>
    </li>
    <li>
     <H4 class='subhead'></H4>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

In the above code, I need to select H3 with class 'head' from any of the H4 elements with class name: 'subhead'. I tried the below code which is not working:

```
alert($(this).prev(".head").text());
```

Can anyone please help me on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert($(this).closest("ul.helper").prev('.head').text());
```

Comment: @Alex i missed that part...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('h4.subhead').click(function () {
    var h3 = $(this).closest('ul.helper').prev('h3');
    console.log(h3, h3.text());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4he7C/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`$(this).parents("h3.head:first")`